# Referencing a cell in Excel using values from other cells in different worksheet (tab)

Tags: microsoft-excel, cells

I'm trying to set up a Excel sheet for a running log.

What I'm trying to do is to get info from a cell that is 7 rows dowm from cell H8 on worksheet Log. This is so that I can just drag the forumla over to other cells, not having to manually do the "= --> mark cell you want --> press enter" for each cell. That would be 365 cells to mark up! o.O

On to the problem:

My initial idea was `Log!H8+7` and the like, but since I'm here that obviously did not work.
I did some searching online and found a few posts talking abot =INDEX, RC[n] and the like, which I have been playing around with for the past hour or so, but I got none of them to work.

So basically I want cell *D6 in worksheet 'Plan'* to refer to the cell *7 rows below H8 in worksheet "Log"*

Anyone that can point me in the right direction?:)

Comment: Can you not create another "sheet"/"page" on the "source" spreadsheet that preemptively provides all the stuff you need on the target spreadsheet?  Or, could you on the target spreadsheet just have an "import" page that just copies (links) the requisite pages from the source spreadsheet?  Trying to do location/index math between spreadsheets just seems like one of the worst of bad ideas.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you're suggesting, but the gist of my workbook is to make a log for running, which I will have to fill in each time I've been out for a run. Hence I cannot provide the information preemptively. 
What I was an easy way to view the information in cell X from sheet A, in cell Y of sheet B.
Note that the cells in sheet A is arranged vertically, and in B horizontally, so dragging forumlas won't work either afaik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the INDIRECT function to calculate or build a cell reference.  It converts something that is a string that looks like a cell reference to an actual cell reference, and you can build that string by combining text and calculations.  You can use it with either "standard" format cell referencing (like A5), or row-column (RC), format.

In standard format, you could do something like:

```
=INDIRECT("Log!H"&8+7)
```

The RC format can be handy for relative addresses, but the benefit is mainly to express a reference relative to the current cell.  For example, if you were on the Log sheet in cell H8, you could use this to reference the cell 7 rows lower:

```
=INDIRECT("R[7]C",0)
```

You need the 0 in the optional last parameter to indicate that the string should be interpreted as an RC style address.  The general format is R8C8 (row 8 column 8, which would be H8).  If the reference is to the current row or column, you can leave off that number.  You can do relative addresses by putting a positive or negative number in brackets, which is the number away from the current position.

This style of addressing can also be useful if you need to calculate a column, since you can do it with numbers instead of letters.  So, for example, say you want to refer to the cell 8 rows down and 3 columns to the left of H8, you could use:

```
=INDIRECT("Log!R"&8+7&"C"&8-3,0)
```

Doing this kind of math in the formula can be useful to develop and debug the formula, or to maintain it.  However, once you don't need it for that, it can overly complicate your formula.  For example, without the need for this math, you could simply use:

```
=Log!H15
```

If the math is required because the value is entered data or is a formula result, don't hard code the value in the formula.  Instead, use a cell reference to where the value is stored.

Comment: Thank you very much for a great explanation. I tried using the first formula you provided, whcih worked just as intenden. Only this made me stumble upon my next problem: it won't be dragged and changing it's value accordingly. Or at least I did not manage to make it do so.
I think I will have to rethink my construction of the workbook a little. 
But again, than you very much for the help.

Comment: @boye - That mention in your question wasn't really clear in terms of exactly what you are trying to accomplish and how you are trying to do it.  Can you provide some more detail?  Are you trying to populate a range of cells and doing it by dragging doesn't change the references to cells on the other sheet?

Comment: Yeah, it was probably not all that clear what my further intentions was. 
The goal was to be able to put in a reference to cell Log!H8 in Plan!E8. Then proceed to refer cell Plan!E9 to the cell Log!H8+7, drag it down, making it "up its value" by 7 from the previous cell. 
Log sheet build: Monday through sunday, vertically.
Plan sheet build: Monday through sunday, horizontally, with weeks going vertically. Hence the need to drag down the reference, increased by seven for each row.

Comment: Continued: 
For Monday Plan!, I'd put in E8: Log!H8
On the following Monday (wk 2) I'd put: Log!H8+7 (or [7 down from previous cell reference]). Then drag it down, making the cell reference move along, down 7 cells each time.
I would then proceed to doing the same for the other days; refering the first week (or two) to a cell in Log, then go on to drag the formula downwards to populate the following weeks.

Comment: Just build the appropriate reference into the formula with math.  The formula for the row reference would be something like: (ROW()-Plan_startrow)*7+first_Log_row. So the row reference to Log for Plan!E9 would calculate as (9-8)*7+8 where the first 9 and 8 refer to rows in Plan and the last 8 refers to the first row in Log.

Comment: From what I read here I work out that in Plan!E9 I should insert the following: =(ROW()-E8)*7+Log!H8
However, this returns #NAME?. What am I doing wrong?
PS: sorry for the late reply, I've been away at work.

Comment: This is just to calculate a row number to use inside an INDIRECT formula to build the cell reference.  Whatever is the first output row number in Plan gets subtracted from the current row to give you the number of entries.  That gets multiplied by 7 because that is your increment, and the result is added to the first row number in Log to locate it properly.  The result (I'll use the placeholder [result]), is just a row number that you use to build a cell reference: INDIRECT("Log!H"&[result])

Comment: As I understand it I need to replace [result] with the (ROW() string. I put this in cell Plan!F9: 
=INDIRECT("Log!H"&(ROW(F8-F9)-F9)*7+Log!H8)
Note: Changed from E8 to F8 (F column, due to redesign)
I have a feeling that I'm not getting how this works. I now got "0" in the cell though.

Comment: If you use a cell reference, like F8 or F9, it replaces the formula reference with the contents of that cell.  If F8 contains the value 39, using F8 in the formula would be like using 39.  If you want just the location of the cell (row or column), just use that number.  F8 is in row 8, so just use 8.  ROW() with no argument returns the row number of the cell it is in.  Say your table in Plan starts in row 3 and you are trying to calculate a lookup location for a cell in row 5.  ROW()-3=2, the number of increments you need on the Log sheet.

Comment: Each increment is 7 rows, so (ROW()-3)*7 tells you that you need a value 14 rows from the top of the data on Log.  Say the data on Log starts in row 2.  (ROW()-3)*7+2=16, which is the actual row number you need to select from on Log to use for the cell in row 5 of Plan.  This is a generic formula, so when you copy it down the column on Plan, ROW() gives you the row number in each row the formula goes in.  So the cell reference would be INDIRECT("Log!H"&(ROW()-3)*7+2) in my example.