# How to increment cell references by 7 rows for each row dragged in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

In Excel 2007 and Google Sheets, I'm trying to drag a formula to populate cells in a column, but I need each successive row to have the cell references incremented by seven rows.  For example, drag this formula:

```
=((E19-E12)+(F19-F12)+(G19-G12)+(H19-H12))*10,0)
```

down to produce:

```
A22=((E19-E12)+(F19-F12)+(G19-G12)+(H19-H12))*10,0)
A23=((E26-E19)+(F26-F19)+(G26-G19)+(H26-H19))*10,0)
A24=((E33-E26)+(F33-F26)+(G33-G26)+(H33-H26))*10,0)
```

and so on.  Therefore increasing the row number by 7 each time.  (daily readings added to weekly readings)

Comment: …and your question is…?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve, dude?

Comment: I am trying to find a way to drag this.  I have to do this for 52 weeks over 4-5 different readings over those weeks.  I was wondering if there is a way to 'automate' the 7 row jump on each line.  Thank you for the help

Comment: There are several existing questions about dragging a formula and having the cell references increment by 7 rows for every row you drag.  See the discussion in the last few comments of this answer: http://superuser.com/a/859102/364367 for the gist of how to do it.  Post back if you still have questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not pretty, but using the `OFFSET` and `ROW` functions you can acheive what you are looking for

```
=(OFFSET($E$19,7*(ROW(A22)-22),0)-OFFSET($E$12,7*(ROW(A22)-22),0))+(OFFSET($F$19,7*(ROW(A22)-22),0)-OFFSET($F$12,7*(ROW(A22)-22),0))+(OFFSET($G$19,7*(ROW(A22)-22),0)-OFFSET($G$12,7*(ROW(A22)-22),0))+(OFFSET($H$19,7*(ROW(A22)-22),0)-OFFSET($H$12,7*(ROW(A22)-22),0))
```

Paste this into cell **A22** and drag down. You might consider putting a totals column in column **I** e.g. formula in cell **I12** would be

```
=SUM($E12:$H12)
```

And also put these formulas in rows 19, 26, 33, etc.. (you can copy and paste that one down)

Then you could use a much simplified formula for weekly difference:

```
=OFFSET($I$19,7*(ROW(A22)-22),0)-OFFSET($I$12,7*(ROW(A22)-22),0)
```